# Запрет на закрытия модального окна кнопкой

Tags: javascript, vue.js

В блоке script во Vue использую

```
$('#ShowModal').modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false
    })
```

Но модальное окно все равно закрывается кнопкой Esc, подскажите как запретить это ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `<div></div>`,
  created() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.pressEscButton);
  },
  destroyed() {
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.pressEscButton);
  },
  methods: {
    pressEscButton($event) {
      if ($event.key === "Escape" || $event.keyCode === 27) { // Escape
        console.log("Aloha");
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
        $event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      }
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```